# Ls -1 Command in linux on Ubuntu dosen't show details beside the name of each directory or file in the list?

Tags: command-line, ls

I am using Ubuntu and when i issue this ls -1 command there is no details appear in-front of the directories and files names there is only a blank space ..what can cause this ?

Comment: `ls -la` or `man ls`

Comment: You seem to miss the difference between the lowercase letter `l` (el) and the number '1' (one). You need the former. Just cut and paste hdbgaf's example., install a different font and/or visit an optometrist. Also closely read the output from `man ls`

Answer (score 3):

That is because you need option `-l` for that. `-a` is to also show hidden files.

Extract from the manual `man ls`:

```
-a, --all
      do not ignore entries starting with .
…
-l     use a long listing format
```

It is the long format that you are looking for.